# How to integrate a cosine-related function

Tags: integration

how to integrate this guy:

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{(\alpha -k\cos\theta)^n}{(\beta-k\cos\theta)^m}\>\text{d}\theta,$$

where $0\leq n\leq m \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $0\leq k\leq \alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}.$

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution ?

Comment: thanks for you suggestion. that's very helpful.